# Analogy between $\mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

When one first learns about covering spaces (e.g. in Ch.1 of Hatcher), one typically learns about $\mathbb{S}^1$ and its universal cover $\mathbb{R}$. When one does calculations $\mod 1$, one lifts to the universal cover and works there instead.

By analogy, I want to think about $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and its "universal cover" $\mathbb{Z}$ as discrete analogues of what is discussed above. Indeed, when one works $\mod m$, one often lifts to the "universal cover" $\mathbb{Z}$, and does basic operation there before "projecting down" to the original space $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

The above two examples are clearly in different categories. The former is in the category of  topological spaces.

My Question: Is there a way to make the analogy more rigorous by formalizing the second example? (In particular, what is the correct notion of "covering space" in this context, and the corresponding notion of "fundamental group"?)

Comment: If $G$ is finitely generated I guess one can form the free group $F$ generated by the generators of $G$ and you certainly have a surjection $F \rightarrow G$ and the kernel describes your lifts, or expression that your generators make that form the identity in $G$.

Comment: The usual analogy is that an embedding $S^1 \to S^3$ is like $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p$. The intuition for this comes from "primes and knots.$ The algebraic notion of finite covering is "etale map." The issue is that there is no naive notion of an algebraic univeral cover. One settles for some kind of "pro"-universality. You may be interested in the etale fundamental group

Comment: In another direction: group homomorphisms $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2$ are in bijection with based homotopy classes of maps $[S^1,\mathbb RP^\infty]=[S^1,\mathbb RP^2]$. More generally, one can form the classifying space (eilenberg-maclane space) $K(\mathbb Z/p,1)$ by using infinite lense spaces to get an analogous statement for any $n$. Basically based maps $[-,K(G,1)]$ is the same as looking at $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(-),G)$.

Answer (score 4):

A simple framework that encapsulates both examples is the notion of a [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence) of (topological) groups; the first is

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

and the second is

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{m} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m \to 0.$$

Writing the second example as

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \frac{1}{m} \mathbb{Z} \to \left( \frac{1}{m} \mathbb{Z} \right) / \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

shows that the second sequence even embeds into the first, and taking the colimit over all $m$ produces the sequence

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

where $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ can be thought of as the group of roots of unity, which is the torsion subgroup of $S^1$. So you can informally think of the second sequence as a "discrete approximation" to the first, which becomes increasingly good but not quite perfect as $m \to \infty$. This can be used to relate, at least informally again, the theory of Fourier series on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and the discrete Fourier transform on $\mathbb{Z}/m$.

Whether this exhibits $\mathbb{Z}$ as the "universal cover" of $\mathbb{Z}/m$ in any sense is unclear to me. It seems to me that there is no way of producing the surjection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m$ from $\mathbb{Z}/m$ functorially; in fact a choice of such a surjection is equivalent to a choice of generator, of which there are $\varphi(m)$. Similarly to produce a surjection $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ would involve picking a basis. But the universal cover is functorial given a basepoint (that is, it's functorial on pointed (nice) path-connected spaces), which for a topological group is conventionally taken to be the identity.